# How again was it

Tags: sentence

Could anyone please explain the part in bold to me. I didn't get it.

▪"    that you convinced me to do this?" the boy said to his friend before they jumped out of the plane on their first sky dive.

Comment: I assume you read this somewhere?  "How was it?" is the question, and "again" is inserted to imply that the speaker knows the question is repeated from earlier but he did not fully comprehend the answer.  (Though sometimes the construction is used in sort of metaphorical sense, were the question was not previously asked.)  Placing "again" where it is above is not "standard", though -- more normal would be to place it after "it" -- but it's writer's choice.

Comment: Thanks ever so much 

Comment: The far more usual positioning of the pragmatic marker (prompting, probably tongue-in-cheek and without there having _been_ an initial explanation, for a repeat of an explanation) is shown: "How was it **again** that you convinced me to do this?" This can be checked by comparing number of tokens of "How was it again that" and "How again was it that" in Google searches. In the idiomatic version, commas are not usually used to offset the parenthetical, which is a rather unusual situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step to understanding the role of *again* here is to realise that it does not modify any particular part of this sentence, but rather the sentence as a whole. Its syntactic role would probably be clearer if it were separated by commas from the rest of the sentence.

What the word conveys is that one is aware that the matter has been discussed before. Why would one raise the matter again, if one is aware of its having been discussed before? It could be, as LPH has explained, that one has forgotten what was said then, and is asking that one's memory be refreshed. If the sentence is taken at face value, that would be the explanation.

The questions of this kind are, however, often used as rhetorical devices, and not intended to be taken literally. Chances are that the boy in the OP's example is not literally asking to be reminded of what was said in some previous conversation. After all, if they are both about to jump, there is no time for that. The boy hasn't literally forgotten the reasons that led him to agree to try sky diving. It is rather that now, that the jump is imminent, the reasons don't seem as convincing as they did before. The sentence was probably intended as a figure of speech, expressing his present fear and hesitation.

One could easily imagine other scenarios in which the questions with *again* would be used in the same way: 'Why, again, are we going on this hike?' (asked as one is waking up, and staying in bed seems much more appealing), 'Why, again, am I supposed to go on a diet?' (asked as one is eyeing a large slice of chocolate cake).

Answer (score 1):

The boy is remembering that a certain reasoning held to him by the person he is talking to was what convinced him to agree to try a sky dive;it happens thouh that he doesn't remember the exact reasons that were given to him; by saying "again" he is expressing the wish to be recalled of that or to recall it himself and he'll probably  try to recollect.

However, I think this turn might be rather colloquial; it doesn't appear in the books ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&content=how+again+was+it%2Chow+was+it+again&direct_url=)). Neither does "how was it again", which sounds better anyway.

You don't find either those two: "how is it again,how again is it" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+again+is+it%2Chow+is+it+again&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&year_end=2008&direct_url=)).; nevertheless, if "how again is it" is not used you can sometimes hear "how is it again".

"What was that again, what is that again" are however standard English ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+was+that+again%2Cwhat+is+that+again&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20was%20that%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20is%20that%20again%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwhat%20was%20that%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20is%20that%20again%3B%2Cc0)). "Again" is explained in those phrases as in the other ones.

Comment: @jsw29 That makes sense, and I suggest to you to make an answer of it, explaining that it is rather your subtle analysis that explains the phrase, but that the basic, or usual interpretation is limited to something close to what I say.